# Moving a lot of objects at once VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I am creating a form that has a lot Picture Boxes (around 2400), I am trying to figure out a way to move all of them all at once instead of it lagging the whole form and taking 10 seconds to move all of them. I am completely stuck. Is it even possible?

I have tried using CType, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That sounds like an all around bad idea. There is overhead involved with every control so having that many individual controls is bad. Most likely, you'd should be using just one `PictureBox` and then using GDI+ to draw everything on that. That will be much, MUCH more efficient. It's hard to say for sure without knowing more about what you're doing but it's hard to see how having that many controls could ever be the best option.

Comment: By the way, `CType` has absolutely nothing to do with moving `PictureBox` controls.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that thousands of controls is generally very bad idea I can suggest placing such controls into single container/control and move that container instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.